# How to detect the land type of a Point in OpenLayers with an OpenStreetMap

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I have an OpenStreetMap

I use OpenLayers

I would like to know if there is a way to get the land type (ex : water, plain, etc) of specific coordinates on the map.

I searched in the documentation but didn't found anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Cloudmade API for Geocoding:
[Cloudmade.com Geocoding API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/geocoding-http-api/Documentation)

You can give Coordinates and for example find roads around the given Coordinates:
http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/geocoding/v2/find.html?object_type=road&around=51.51384,-0.10952

You can return this information also in Json format

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tested this API, it's very interesting and cool.
Unfortunately, I could not have results with the object_type "water"

Comment: I mean, sometimes it find water, but when i click on the Atlantic it returns nothing. I suppose the BDD is not complete.